# spring-security-oauth2 - checkClientDetails from Resource Server

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I am working on an OAuth 2.0 Resource Server app, using spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.  I am able to secure a resource to a specific scope, but noticed when spring-security-oauth2 runs through the OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter, it eventually executes OAuth2AuthenticationManager.checkClientDetails().  That method calls clientDetailsService.loadClientbyClientId().

My question is, should I register a ClientDetailsService in a Resource Server?  Based on the Spring OAuth developer guide, I thought the ClientDetialsService was only required for Authorization Server implementations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In `OAuth2AuthenticationManager.checkClientDetails()`, if the `clientDetailsService` is null, it just return peacefully without doing anything. So, it is ok to leave `clientDetailsService` null as default.

If it is not null, the authentication manager will check the requested scopes are allowed by client details returned from `clientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId()`.

Spring provides `InMemoryClientDetailsService` and `JdbcClientDetailsService`. In my opinion, the first one only can be used when combining auth server and resource server in the same site. The second need a jdbc connection from resource server to a database that auth server used to store the client details.

The best solution may be implementing a `RemoteClientDetailsService` to get client details from a customized auth server endpoint(like /oauth/check_client), as what the `RemoteTokenServices` dose.